# Having trouble adding an icon for my javaFX login screen

Tags: java

I have been trying to add an image as an application icon but I keep getting an invocationTargetException error and I can' figure out why.

I've been following lots of online tutorials and nothing seems to work.

My code and the trace error is as follows:

```
package store;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LogInFX extends Application {

String userName;
String password;
private Image icon;

public LogInFX(){
    
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
   GridPane root = new GridPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 225);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setHgap(10);
    root.setVgap(10);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(15, 25, 25, 25));
    
    Text title = new Text("Welcome");
    title.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
    
    Button logIn = new Button();
    Label user = new Label("Username: ");
    Label pwd = new Label("Password: ");
    
    TextField userField = new TextField();
    PasswordField pwdField = new PasswordField();
    
    logIn.setText("Login");
    logIn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            userName = userField.getText();
            password = pwdField.getText();
            
            root.getChildren().clear();
            
            if(userName.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
                OwnerFX o = new OwnerFX(userName, password);
                o.start(primaryStage);
            }
            if(!userName.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
                Customer cust = new Customer(userName, password, "Null", 0);
                if(cust.checkCust(userName, password) == true){
                    CustomerFX c = new CustomerFX(userName, password);
                    c.makeCust(primaryStage, userName, password);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    root.add(title, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    root.addRow(1, user, userField);
    root.addRow(2, pwd, pwdField);
    root.addRow(3, logIn);
    
    Image applicationIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("book.png"));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(applicationIcon);
    
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
> at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1128)
> at javafx.scene.image.Image.(Image.java:706)
> at store.LogInFX.start(LogInFX.java:80)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
> ... 1 more
> Exception running application store.LogInFX

Comment: I think your `book.png` path is incorrect. At least the application encounters a NullPointerException while trying to validate an InputStream, and the only InputStream I can see you handling in your code is `getClass().getResourceAsStream("book.png")`, and the class you feed it to appears in the stacktrace

Comment: This part of the stack trace is your problem: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null`. This means that `getResourceAsStream()` is returning null. Where is file `book.png` located relative to file `LogInFX.class`?

Comment: Hi so the book.png file is located within my source folder, basically I have a folder called store in my source and within that store folder I have my classes along with the picture

Comment: If your images are in the `store` folder, you must specify that folder in the path:`/store/book.png`